# Use Find and Replace feature in an Excel shared workbook

Tags: excel

In my work place, we share an Excel workbook, which only 2MB.....
These days, my colleagues report an issue that the workbook is slow and sometimes gaps occur in the spreadsheet.
They believe the reason is I open the find and replace window and use the find feature. Instead, I should use the search box in the filter to avoid this issue.

Base on my knowledge, I don't think it is the right cause, because there is not different between filter and find, they are both editing features.

Additionally, when open the Share Workbook feature, one user will appear multiple times in the "who has this workbook open now", in fact they only open one.

Would anyone please explain the cause of the issue?

Thanks a lot.

Comment: AFAIK, after you do the find/replace, the size or speed of the workbook shouldn't really change.  They're saying that, because you do find/replace, even after that's complete, and you re-save the document, that it's causing the workbook to function slowly?  Are there any formulas in the workbook, or macros?

Comment: There is data validation on some columns, and only one column have the V lookup function. Mostly they have problems when they operate filter, search or edit/input data.